# Jmeter - Transaction Controller with enabling Generate Parent sample

Tags: jmeter

In my load test homepage i am having 10 api calls and i am using;
Transaction controller with Generate Parent sample
They ask me the report by enabling Generate Parent sample

1. without enabling Generate Parent sample my result with response time is good
2. But with enabling Generate Parent sample my result responses are with huge delay, why this delay which result is correct

Note : i am using 10 api which does not has child things like css, js,etc

My configuration looks like
i am using constant throughput timer - 30.0 for all active threads
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If "they ask" you and you're obeying then why you're asking us in your turn instead of "them"?

[Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller) in "Generate Parent Sample" mode returns cumulative elapsed time of **all its children**.

To wit if you have 10 API calls under the Transaction Controller in "Generate parent sample" mode the Transaction Controller' "elapsed" time will be the **sum of all its children** (either [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or other [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

We don't know which result is correct as well because it depend on the business use cases of your API with end users or upstream systems and the [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) and/or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)